# Cut-off first letter by ajax

Tags: javascript

I am using currency package in laravel where it returns values with their prefix together such as `$10` or `€6`.

The issue is that I am getting these prices by ajax and sum them together `e.g. product price + size price` then i get total price of the user order, problem is while i have these prefixes `$` or `€` i cannot calculate prices `numbers` so i need to remove those letters from prices in my JavaScript, I have tried some ways that I found on the net such as `slice(1)` and `substring(1)` none of them gave me the result i'm looking for.

here is my code:

```
<script>
 var start_price = parseFloat($('#price').attr('data-price'));
 $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(start_price)); //default price
    $("#installation").click(function(){
        var amountToAdd = 0;
        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
              maximumFractionDigits:0, 
              minimumFractionDigits:0
          });
        $("#installation").each(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                amountToAdd += parseFloat($(this).val());
                $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(amountToAdd+start_price)); // change with installation price
            } else{
                $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(start_price)); // back to default price
            }
        });
        $('#price').text(nf.format(parseFloat(amountToAdd+start_price)));
   });
</script>
```

### What I need

cut prefixes from `start_price` and `amountToAdd`

### extra question

as I'm using several currency not all my currencies have `1` letter prefix, some of them have `2` prefix.

e.g.

`$10`
`Rp100000`

as you see my other currency prefix is `rp` which is 2 letter.

**Q:** how do I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a regex [.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove all non-numeric characters from the string. This would remove all currency symbols, regardless of the symbol or its character length. You could use it like this:

```
<script>
    var start_price = parseFloat($('#price').attr('data-price').replace(/\D/g,'')); //HERE
    $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(start_price)); //default price
    $("#installation").click(function(){
        var amountToAdd = 0;
        var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
          maximumFractionDigits:0, 
          minimumFractionDigits:0
        });
        $("#installation").each(function() {
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                amountToAdd += parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'')); //AND HERE
                $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(amountToAdd+start_price)); // change with installation price
            } else{
                $('#finalprice').val(parseFloat(start_price)); // back to default price
            }
        });
        $('#price').text(nf.format(parseFloat(amountToAdd+start_price)));
    });
</script>
```

If you need to modify the regex at some point, this can be a useful tool to find one that works for you: [https://regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)